# Using Google Maps API to quickly let user select address

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So I thought it would be a smart idea to use a combination of Google Maps API and Autocomplete API for customers to quickly look up their address. The added bonus is that I can always trust the format in which the address comes in.

After digging a bit through the Terms of Use, it seems that you are only allowed to store the Place ID. This seems against the thing I'm trying to achieve, because I need the actual location / address of the customer in my DB.

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms/#5-places-api

Should I just forget about using Google services for this purposes and revert back to asking the user to type the address themselves? Seems like against the purpose for Google even offering autocomplete services. They even show how to put the received data in a form, so it seems a bit contradictory: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#address_forms

Any alternatives for this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is to store the Place ID for each of your users address when they sign up, and everytime that you'll need to access on what is the address of a user, you'll need to call for a [Geocoding request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) so you can retrieve the address in proper format. This is usually what others do in order to prevent breaching the ToS(Terms of Service)

Note: Please be mindful of the 30 days allowed time for storing the Place IDs, after 30 days, you may call a Geocoding request for the Place IDs and store those again in your DB, this will also help your record be up to date in case there are changes in Place IDs of the places that is stored in your DB

P.S. sorry I can't comment this one as it is too long.

Comment: So what about prepolulating a browser side form with data from the JavaScript API, if the user submits that form, the data is basically provided by the user. I think this couldn’t be considered a break of TOS, what dot you think?

Comment: As long as the data came from the user and not from the API then it will not be breach of ToS :)

Comment: Well, that’s a matter of interpretation.., technically anything that’s submitted from a client side through a form could be considered as coming from the user, even if the original data was fetched through Google Javascriot API, especially when it’s only presented as a suggestion to the user and allow them to change.